# Spotlight reports "Indexing and searching disabled" in Lion

Tags: macos, spotlight

Lion keeps "losing track" of Spotlight information. Directories and Applications disappear, full text searches stop working, etc. I seem to need to re-index it once a week or so.

However, now it appears to not work at all.

Running

```
sudo mdutil -i on /
```

from the Terminal I get a message

```
"Indexing and searching disabled."
```

I have tried trashing preference files, deleting the whole V100 folder, repairing permssions, etc but Spotlight still thinks indexing is turned off on my entire Volume (Yes have added/deleted whole disk from Spotlight's privacy preferences").

In the console I have quite a few errors that look like this

```
mds: (Error) Server: Disabled store registered for scope "/Applications"
```

However, I do not know how to tell it to re-enable that scope as mdutil gives an error when I try to turn on indexing and gives an error when I try to delete the index

EDIT: I reinstalled Lion. It did not fix the problem(s) :(

Comment: Are you using some "cleanup" tool by chance? Some of them are overly aggressive and delete the spotlight index.

Comment: nope, no cleanup tools.

Comment: You could try flushing your cache and rebuilt it with the following command: sudo mdutil -pEsav. The command you are running just turns it on, but it may be chocking for a different reason. How much space do you have free on the drive (how much taken)? And what are the errors you receive from mdutil?

Comment: I second running `sudo mdutil -pEsav`. My timemachien drive was constantly being indexed. After running that and waiting for spotlight to finish the rebuild I had no more problems.

Comment: As mentioned, that doesn't work because Spotlight thinks it is disabled. Running the above command gets me:

Indexing and searching disabled.
Error: datastore publishing not implemented.

Comment: Could you show us your `/.Spotlight-V100/VolumeConfiguration.plist`?

Comment: @Ingmar - I deleted that entire folder in a futile bid to get Spotlight to recreate the index. It has never re-created it.

Comment: When you say that you reinstalled Lion, does that mean that you did a completely clean reinstall or did you restore data from a backup?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I had the exact same problem, with all solutions above failing identically. Then I reexamined the directory listing for `/` and found a hidden file `.metadata_never_index` in the root directory. I removed this file and was able to turn spotlight on again with 
`mdutil -i` on `/`.

`mds` is now reindexing the hard disk, all looks good for now.

Comment: I had this same problem after imaging. This solution worked for me :)! More than a year later.

Comment: THANK YOU! Been trying to get this to work for a couple months on work laptop. I did sudo rm .metadata_never_index, then ran your mdutil -i on / and it said "Indexing enabled." Now I finally get the indexing graph!

Comment: This fixed it for me as well, however the issue comes up again after I rebooted. The `.metadata_never_index` file reappeared in `/`. However, it's possible that the reason is I simply ran the command `sudo mdutil -a -i on` (without specifying `\` at the end).

Comment: This solution worked for me on a fresh install of macOS Sierra 10.12.6, December 2017

Answer (score 28):

```
sudo mdutil -i off /
sudo rm -rf /.Spotlight*
sudo mdutil -i on /
sudo mdutil -E /
```

1 - turn indexing off

2 - delete Spotlight folder

3 - turn indexing on

4 - rebuild

Does this help?

Also it [seems](http://www.mikesel.info/disable-spotlight/) you could use these commands:

```
sudo mdutil -a -i off
sudo mdutil -a -i on
```

Comment: No, when I try that on any Volume or subset of a Volume I get the following, as mentioned

Indexing and searching disabled.

Comment: I know it has something to do with the MDS error messages in the log (mds: (Error) Server: Disabled store registered for scope XXXX) but I don't know why/how those are disabled

Comment: @lemonginger: Step 2,`rm -rf /.Spotlight*`, fails with *"permission denied"*. I'm stuck.

Comment: Try with sudo rm , I edited my above post

Comment: @maggix: I'd tried that too (good suggestion), but it also fails.

Comment: For me `mdutil -i on /` did not enable indexing at first but it was enabled after I rebooted.

Comment: Worked for me. This was on an almost clean macOS installation. Funny it broke so fast.

Answer (score 11):

The other solutions didn't work for me, however the following was the culprit in my case.

Make sure your root/main hard drive isn't in the "privacy" settings for spotlight. For some reason I had the whole hard drive under the "Prevent spotlight from indexing the following locations" list.

You can access this section from System Preferences -> Spotlight -> Privacy

Comment: This was the key for me.  The volume I wanted to index was in the Privacy window.  Clicking minus (-) removed it.  Then I could apply the steps outlined by maggix.  I had to 'enable' twice, once for searching, and then for indexing.  Same command both times:  sudo mdutil -i on /

Comment: WARNING:  I have a two-system hard-disk divided into two Volumes.  When I add the volume I'm NOT using to the Spotlight -> Privacy panel, I discover it appears in the OTHER Volume's Privacy panel as well.  So when I restart onto the OTHER Volume, it's in its own Privacy panel?!!  NOT what I expected, especially since each Volume has its own .Spotlight-V100 directory.  Is this an Apple bug?

Comment: This solved the issue for me! :) Thanks! :)

Comment: The unique solution that works for me! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo mdutil -i off /
sudo rm -rf /.Spotlight*
sudo rm -rf /.metadata_never_index
sudo mdutil -i on /
sudo mdutil -E /
```

A combination of the above worked for me.  Step 3 was the big one.  Got rid of the "Indexing and searching disabled." message.  Then steps 4 and 5 worked as expected.

1. turn indexing off
2. delete Spotlight folder
3. delete metadata file
4. turn indexing on
5. rebuild

Comment: this worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

After all of the initial troubleshooting steps:

- Rebuild the index
- Attempt in another user account
- Dump prefs/cache and start over

I found the issue lied in what was enabled/disabled. In terminal, I ran "mdutil -sa" and got:

```
/:
    Indexing enabled. 
/Groups:
    Indexing disabled. 
/Shared Items/Public:
    Indexing disabled.
/Users:
    Indexing disabled. 
/Users/sarah/Documents:
    Indexing enabled.
```

I noticed "/Users: Indexing disabled." That's the problem there. The fix: "sudo mdutil -i on /Users". After that, it re-indexed /Users, which took significantly longer than it had before, and before it was finished, it was searching my Mail!

Answer (score 3):

This can also be caused by getting stuck in safe mode.  To fix that, you need to reset the  NVRAM by holding down the <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>, <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>, and <kbd>R</kbd> keys immediately after rebooting (before the gray screen appears).

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this issue after my `iMac` installed the software update `10.7.4` to my machine. Most of the suggested command-lines would produce `'Indexing and searching disabled'`. `sudo mdutil -pEsav` gave me `'datastore publishing not implemented.'`

Below is the solution that worked:

- edit `/etc/hostconfig`
- add the line  `SPOTLIGHT=-YES-` at the bottom (this line was missing)
- reboot

(after reboot make some soup while your machine prepares the index)

Answer (score 1):

Only the combination of `-E` and `-i on` worked for me:

```
sudo mdutil -E -i on /Volumes/blah
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: [Re-enable Spotlight Indexing](http://www.cryan.com/blog/20150821.jsp)

> ```
> sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist
> ```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried for days about every solution out there for Big Sur, and the combination of these steps seemed to solve it for me. Trust me I didn't want do disable system integrity either but it's the only thing that worked:

1. Disable system integrity (restart -> hold cmd + r -> select utilities terminal -> csrutil disable -> restart again)
2. run

```
sudo rm /System/Volumes/Data/.metadata_never_index
```

3. run

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist
```

4. run

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist
```

5. Reenable system integrity `csrutil enable` following steps in step #1

Specifically the problem I had was I could not search applications. As you can see in the image, I can now see the application and it will successfully open it.
Also, notice the index loading indicator:

[image]