# What is `IMDPersistenceAgent` and error in `com.apple.corespotlight.log.index`?

Tags: macos, spotlight, error, logs

I am see this appear repeatedly in my log.

```
Jan  6 18:23:46 johndoe-macbook com.apple.spotlight.IndexAgent[12337]: [com.apple.corespotlight.log] Not allowed to pass in bundle ID
Jan  6 18:23:46 johndoe-macbook IMDPersistenceAgent[12376]: [com.apple.corespotlight.log.index] Finished "index items"(48) with error:Error Domain=CSIndexErrorDomain Code=-1003 "(null)"
Jan  6 18:23:46 johndoe-macbook IMDPersistenceAgent[12376]: [Warning] IMDChatAddMessageToSpotlight: deleting message for searchable items failed with error Error Domain=CSIndexErrorDomain Code=-1003 "(null)"
Jan  6 18:23:46 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
```

What is the `IMDPersistenceAgent` process?

What is the problem causing these error messages? Any fix?

Comment: That's a process used by Messages.  Try reindexing spotlight and see if that helps.  See [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/142523/88313) for the steps to do that.