# macOS Sierra Spotlight search does not find Numbers but Number

Tags: macos, spotlight

My Spotlight search behaves strange and I don't know how to fix it. 
Any Ideas?

When I want to open Numbers, I hit <kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd>  and start typing "number",

[image: spotlight screenshot]

but if I keep on typing the "s", essentially completing the app name Numbers, Spotlight does not know what to do anymore.

[image]

Does the index point into a wrong direction? If I search for a specific file it works.

I tried the solutions by Anil and Senseful [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62715/applications-dont-show-up-in-spotlight), but the problem does not change

**UPDATE**

After rebuilding the Spotlight library the problem shortly disappeared (one week). But it returned again. So maybe my question is not how to solve this problem but **what is corrupting my Spotlight index?**

Interestingly the Spotlight results look a bit different now and shows the App-Store Numbers version (which then automatically opens the local one).

[image]

Comment: thank you @user3439894 for reformatting, I was writing it up while my head was still unsettled. However, I think I should have amphasized a lot more what I already did instead of (just) mentioning the authors of those entries.

Comment: Did either of these answers help you with your issue? If yes, please up-vote answers and accept answer as appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first do as suggested in Hefewe1zen's [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/283573/macos-sierra-spotlight-search-does-not-find-numbers-but-number/283596#283596), rebuild the Spotlight index on your Mac.

If that doesn't fix the issue, then the next thing I'd try is rebuilding the Launch Services Database.

In Terminal:

```
/S*/L*/F*/C*/F*/L*/S*/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

I always use the short form of the *command* above, however here is the long form:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

There is no manual page for `lsregister` however, the following *command* outputs the internal help file:

```
/S*/L*/F*/C*/F*/L*/S*/lsregister --help
```

If you want to read more about rebuilding the Launch Services Database, Google is your friend!

If by chance neither of these suggested answers work, then I'd reinstall Numbers.

Comment: I am not totally sure when Spotlight worked again. In any case using the terminal commands from the other entry and than using this command solved the problem eventually.

Answer (score 4):

I would start by rebuilding the Spotlight index.

From: [How to rebuild the Spotlight index on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716)

> 1. Choose Apple menu () > System Preferences, then click Spotlight.
> 2. Click the Privacy tab.
> 3. Drag the folder or disk that you want to index again to the list of locations that Spotlight is prevented from searching. Or click the
>      Add (+) button and select the folder or disk to add.
>      To add an item to the Privacy tab, you must have ownership permissions for that item. To learn about permissions, choose Help
>      from the Finder menu bar, then search for “permissions.”
> 4. From the same list of locations, select the folder or disk that you just added. Then click the Remove (–) button to remove it from the
>      list.
> 5. Quit System Preferences. Spotlight will reindex the contents of the folder or disk.

Or via Terminal:

```
sudo mdutil -i off /
sudo mdutil -i on /
sudo mdutil -E
```

See the [man page for `mdutil`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mdutil.1.html) or type `man mdutil` in Terminal.

Comment: To whomever down-voted this answer, why!? IMO, its a valid step to take! (Even if it doesn't fix the issue!) +1

Comment: Didn't down vote and I agree with @user3439894 ...though you should include the steps to rebuild the index in the answer because links to Apple do (and often) change making them stale.

Comment: @Allan, I agree with at least a minimum summarizing if to long, although in this case was short enough to just copy the steps and quoted it and where from. Also added man page link/info for `mdutil` however, that said he at least included the Terminal commands, so not quoting the Apple support article shouldn't be grounds to automatically down-vote in this particular case.

Comment: @user3439894 -  Let me punctuate your last sentence because I agree - there was ***zero*** reason to down vote this answer.

Comment: only the terminal version worked. Using System Preferences (making my HD private and than removing it) did not work, even though I restarted/log-off/on.

Comment: Glad to hear you fixed it