# Spotlight not finding folders, files, or apps in High Sierra

Tags: spotlight, encryption, apfs

I can't be sure it's related but after I turned on File Encryption Spotlight just stopped working on files folders and apps. I tried all the advice I saw in [this post on this forum](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62715/applications-dont-show-up-in-spotlight) and more, including reinstalling the OS and resetting parameter RAM and deleting the .Spotlight-V100 folder.

I found the answer today and it took so long I thought it was worth posting both the question and the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on [this post](https://discussions.apple.com/message/32634056#message32634056) in an Apple Community forum.

The key was to **rebuild the Launch Services Database** - I didn’t even know that was a thing. You need to use the terminal and run this command:

```
sudo /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain u -domain s -domain l -v
```

Takes a minute or so to complete and you get a lot of lines with errors. Then I continued with the advice in the post to rebuild the indexing with the following

```
sudo mdutil -i on /
sudo mdutil -E /
```

After running for just a few minutes I started to see apps show back up in Spotlight.

Hope I can save someone else a few weeks of pain and searching.