# Issues with internal flash storage drive, time machine and spotlight

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, disk-utility, ssd, spotlight

Anyone experienced similar issues that my internal drive, where OS X is installed is looking like this (About This Mac --> Storage).
[image]

Also Finder can not see second partition of the drive. On top of that when opening Disk Utility it loads for really long and almost freezes. Trying to mount second partition from Disk Utility does nothing. I have run First Aid, have reset PRAM, still nothing. Additionally when this happened now the Spotlight can’t find any applications either. I followed these steps, still no luck: [Applications Don't Show Up in Spotlight](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62715/applications-dont-show-up-in-spotlight)
Is my M2 SSD dying or what is happening. How could I verify that?

Also Time Machine fails to make any successful backups to external disk, complains that (previously was working fine):

> An error occurred while copying files. The problem may be temporary. If the problem persists, use Disk Utility to repair your backup disk.

All this started after a MacBook restart.

I have MacBook Pro 15" from 2015 and running Mac OSX version 10.14.6

Comment: I'm assuming this is a USB thumb drive. There are multiple problems alluded to here: malfunctioning flash drive; spotlight inconsistencies; Time Machine failures. We you relying on this thumb drive as a macOS boot disk?

Comment: No, it is integrated flash M2 drive/SSD, the Time Machine backup is done to the external HDD, but just wanted to point out that the errors seems to be related to the main integrated drive, even though the error message points finger to the external drive

Comment: Also additional point it seems that the index is completely screwed. Can't search even my Mail application messages. The search results just dont return anything...

Comment: If you could edit your question to specify that the drive is an internal SSD, that would make things clearer. You call it a 'flash storage drive' in the title, which is a little confusing. From your description of what's happening, the SSD is not healthy, and its disk structure has become corrupt. If your Time Machine backup has been working normally, and has been backing up the boot and the second partition (that you cannot now access) you should be able to reformat the SSD with Recovery and use the Time Machine backup to put it all back.

Comment: Additionally, I stopped partitioning drives a few years ago when the costs of additional disks, or bigger disks, went down. Personally, I see no point in partitioning a SSD drive, but you will not see any [performance issues](https://superuser.com/questions/808833/disadvantages-of-partitioning-an-ssd).

Comment: Thank IconDaemon, yeah, seems that my SSD is dying. Tried to run Repair from recovery, but that failed. Also tried reinstalling Mac OS X and that also failed due to corrupt drive.