# Unable to create directory under /usr

Tags: filesystem

I'm porting a program from Linux and Windows to macOS, and we use `/usr/tmp`, I can switch to `/usr/local`, but it puzzles me why not root can create a directory there that I can `chown` and use with my program.

```
$ sudo whoami
root
$ whoami
mobj
$ sudo mkdir /usr/tmp
mkdir: /usr/tmp: Operation not permitted
$ ls -ld /usr/
drwxr-xr-x@ 11 root  wheel  352 Nov  2 23:44 /usr/
$ sudo mkdir /usr/local/tmp
$ sudo chown mobj:dist /usr/local/tmp
$ ls -ld /usr/local/tmp
drwxr-xr-x  2 mobj  dist  64 Nov 23 12:07 /usr/local/tmp
```

Comment: See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/388236/unable-to-create-folder-in-root-of-macintosh-hd

Comment: @lhf Not sure this still works with SSV.

Comment: Being root doesn't have the "god" status like on other Unixes, and confers very few benefits over an admin user with sudo. And leaves all your doors open.

Comment: On a Unix, you should be using /usr/local/bin anyway for your binaries and $TEMP for wherever you are keeping temporary files.

Comment: I have used many Unixes and have never had a temporary director in /usr/tmp - the correct directory now and especially on macOS is use the environment variable $TMPDIR - and older way that usually works but be careful on multi user machines is /tmp. Windows often has a varible but  he correct way is to call the Windows API to get the temp directory - as it is for macOS and POSIX only use the environment variable if you language has a poor library like bash - any hard coded directory is a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple restricts changes to a number of directories, including usr.

See: https://support.apple.com/en-us/102149